# Red black tree deletion

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, red-black-tree

I'm having trouble in writing a red-black tree deletion function (with sentinels).

After many hours of trouble shooting I came to the conclusion that the problem arises in the following steps:

Inserting 14, 11, 7 and 8 and then deleting 11 (which is the root).

11 is replaced with 14 which has no children. Then, x (see the code) gets the value of the NULL node - which makes functions like x.parent meaningless (am I right?)

Then the program stops in a null exception.

Any ideas what is the problem?

*I hope that I've made my self clear - if not I'd be happy to give more information.

Thanks!

The entire relevant code:

```
public class RBTree {

    private RBNode DUMMYROOT;
    private RBNode NULL;
    private int numOfNodes;


    public RBTree() {
        this.numOfNodes=0;
        this.NULL = new RBNode();
        this.DUMMYROOT = new RBNode();

        this.DUMMYROOT.setKey(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        this.DUMMYROOT.setLeftChild(NULL);
        this.DUMMYROOT.setColor("black");
        this.NULL.setColor("black");

    }

    public RBNode getNULL() {
        return this.NULL;
    }

  /**
   * public boolean empty()
   * 
   * returns true if and only if the tree is empty
   *  
   */


  public boolean empty() {
    if (this.numOfNodes==0)
        return true;
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * public boolean search(int i)
   * 
   * returns true if and only if the tree contains i
   *  
   */
  public boolean search(double i) {
      return (recursiveSearch(i, this.DUMMYROOT.getLeftChild())!=NULL);
  }

  public RBNode searchNode(double i) {
      return recursiveSearch(i, this.DUMMYROOT.getLeftChild());
  }


  private RBNode recursiveSearch(double i, RBNode rbNode) {
      if (rbNode==NULL)
          return NULL;
      else if (rbNode.getKey()==i)
          return rbNode;
      else if (rbNode.getKey()<i)
          return recursiveSearch(i,rbNode.getRightChild());
      else
          return recursiveSearch(i,rbNode.getLeftChild());
}

/**
   * public void insert(int i)
   * 
   * inserts the integer i into the binary tree; the tree
   * must remain valid (keep its invariants).
   * the function returns the number of color flips, or 0 if i was already in the tree
   * 
   */
  public int insert(int i) {
       RBNode rb = new RBNode(i);
       if (this.search((double)i)==false) {
           this.numOfNodes++;
           return RBTreeInsert(this,rb);
       }
       return 0;
  }

  private RBNode treePosition(RBNode x, double k) {
       RBNode y=x;
       while (x!=NULL) {
          y=x;
          if (x.getKey()==k)
              return x;
          else if (x.getKey()>k)
              x=x.getLeftChild();
          else
              x=x.getRightChild();
       }
       return y;
  }

  private int RBTreeInsert(RBTree t, RBNode z) {
       RBNode y;
       y=treePosition(t.DUMMYROOT,z.getKey());
       if (z.getKey()!=y.getKey()) {
           z.setParent(y);
           z.setLeftChild(NULL);
           z.setRightChild(NULL);
           z.setColor("red");
           if (z.getKey()<y.getKey())
               y.setLeftChild(z);
           else
               y.setRightChild(z);
       }
       return RBTreeInsertFixUp(z,t);
  }


   private int RBTreeInsertFixUp(RBNode node, RBTree t) {

       int counter =0;

       if(this.empty()==true)
               return counter;

       while(node.parent.color.equals("red")){
        if(node.parent == node.parent.parent.leftChild){
            RBNode y = node.parent.parent.rightChild;

            //case 1
            if(y.color.equals("red")){
                counter+=3;
                node.parent.setColor("black");
                y.setColor("black");
                node.parent.parent.setColor("red");
                node = node.parent.parent;
            }

            //case 2
            else {
                if(node == node.parent.rightChild) {
                    node = node.parent;
                    leftRotate(node, t);
                }
            //case 3
                counter+=2;
                node.parent.setColor("black");
                node.parent.parent.setColor("red");
                rightRotate(node.parent.parent, t);
            }

        }

        else {
            RBNode y = node.parent.parent.leftChild;

            //case 1
            if(y.color.equals("red")){
                counter+=3;
                node.parent.setColor("black");
                y.setColor("black");
                node.parent.parent.setColor("red");
                node = node.parent.parent;
            }

            //case 2
            else {
                if (node == node.parent.leftChild) {
                    node = node.parent;
                    rightRotate(node, t);
                }
            //case 3
                counter+=2;
                node.parent.setColor("black");
                node.parent.parent.setColor("red");
                leftRotate(node.parent.parent, t);
            }

        }
    }

    if(!(this.DUMMYROOT.leftChild.color.equals("black"))) {
        this.DUMMYROOT.leftChild.setColor("black");
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;


}

    private void rightRotate(RBNode node, RBTree t) {
            RBNode y = node.leftChild;
            Transplant(node, y);
            leftChild(node, y.rightChild);
            rightChild(y, node);
        }

    private void leftRotate(RBNode node, RBTree t) {
            RBNode y = node.rightChild;
            Transplant(node,y);
            rightChild(node, y.leftChild);
            leftChild(y,node);

            }

    private void Transplant(RBNode node, RBNode y) {
            if(node == node.parent.leftChild)
                leftChild(node.parent, y);
            else
                rightChild(node.parent,y);
        }

    private void rightChild(RBNode node, RBNode y) {
            node.rightChild =y;
            y.parent = node;

    }

    private void leftChild(RBNode node, RBNode y) {
            node.leftChild = y;
            y.parent = node;

        }


  /**
   * public void delete(int i)
   * 
   * deletes the integer i from the binary tree, if it is there;
   * the tree must remain valid (keep its invariants).
   * the function returns the number of color flips, or 0 if i was not in the tree
   * 
   */
   public int delete(int i)
   {
       if (this.search(i)==true) {
           //deletion will be made, so we decrease numOfNodes by 1
           this.numOfNodes--;
           return RBTreeDelete(this.searchNode(i),this);
       }
       return 0;
   }

   public int RBTreeDelete(RBNode deleteNode, RBTree tree){

       RBNode y;
       RBNode x;

       if(this.empty() == true)
           return 0;

       if(deleteNode.getLeftChild() == this.NULL || deleteNode.getRightChild() == this.NULL)
           y = deleteNode;
       else {
           y = TreeSuccessor(deleteNode); 

       }

       if(y.leftChild != NULL)
           x = y.leftChild;
       else
           x = y.rightChild;

       x.parent = y.parent;
       if(y.parent == NULL)
           DUMMYROOT.leftChild = x;
       else if(y == y.parent.leftChild)
           y.parent.leftChild = x;
       else
           y.parent.rightChild = x;

       if(y != deleteNode)
           deleteNode.key = y.key;

       if (y.color.equals("black")==true) 
               return RBDeleteFixUp(tree, x);

       return 0; //counter is 0, no color changes should be made. if me made any - they will be returned by "RBDleteFixUp"
   }

   private int RBDeleteFixUp(RBTree T, RBNode x) {
       //counts color changes
       int counter2= 0;
       boolean b=true;
       RBNode w = new RBNode();

       if(this.empty()==true)
           return counter2;

       while(((x != DUMMYROOT.leftChild)) &&  x.color.equals("black") && b==true){
           if(x == x.parent.leftChild){
               w = x.parent.rightChild;
               //case 1
               if(w.color.equals("red")){
                   System.out.println("1");

                   w.setColor("black");
                   counter2++;
                   x.parent.setColor("red");
                   counter2++;
                   leftRotate(x.parent, T);
                   w = x.parent.rightChild;
               }

               //case2


               if((w.rightChild.color.equals("black")) && (w.leftChild.color.equals("black"))){
                   System.out.println("2");
                   w.setColor("red");
                   counter2++;
                   x = x.parent;
               }

               //case 3
               else {
                   if(w.rightChild.color.equals("black")){
                       System.out.println("3");

                   w.leftChild.setColor("black");
                   counter2++;
                   w.setColor("red");
                   counter2++;
                   rightRotate(w, T);
                   w = x.parent.rightChild;

               }

               //case 4
                   System.out.println("4");
                        w.color = x.parent.color;
                        counter2++;
                        x.parent.setColor("black");
                        counter2++;
                        w.rightChild.setColor("black");
                        counter2++;
                        leftRotate(x.parent, T);
                        x = DUMMYROOT.leftChild;


               }
           }

           else{

               w = x.parent.leftChild;
               //case 1
               if(w.color.equals("red")){
                   System.out.println("5");
                   w.setColor("black");
                   counter2++;
                   x.parent.setColor("red");
                   counter2++;
                   rightRotate(x.parent, T);
                   w = x.parent.leftChild;
               }

               //case2

               if(w.rightChild.color.equals("black") && w.leftChild.color.equals("black")){
                   System.out.println("6");
                   w.setColor("red");
                   counter2++;
                   x = x.parent;
               }

               //case 3
               else {
                   if(w.leftChild.color.equals("black")){
                       System.out.println("7");
                   w.rightChild.setColor("black");
                   counter2++;
                   w.setColor("red");
                   counter2++;
                   leftRotate(w, T);
                   w = x.parent.leftChild;

                   }

               //case 4
               /**
               if(!(w.color == x.parent.color)){
                   w.color = x.parent.color;
                   counter2++;
               }
               **/ 

                   System.out.println("8");

                       w.color = x.parent.color;
                       counter2++;
                       x.parent.setColor("black");
                       counter2++;

                       w.leftChild.setColor("black"); //HERE THERES A NULL EXCEPTION
                       counter2++;             
                       rightRotate(x.parent, T);
                       x = DUMMYROOT.leftChild;

               }
           }
       }

       x.setColor("black");
       counter2++;
       return counter2;

    }

    private RBNode TreeSuccessor(RBNode node) {
        RBNode x = new RBNode();
        RBNode y = new RBNode();
        x=node;

        if (x.getRightChild()!=this.NULL) {
            return minNode(x.getRightChild());
        }
        y=x.getParent();
        while ((y!=this.NULL) && (x==y.getRightChild())) {
            x=y;
            y=x.getParent();
        }
        return y;
    }

       public RBNode minNode(RBNode startNode) {
           RBNode currNode= new RBNode();
           currNode=startNode;
           if (currNode==this.NULL) {
               System.out.println("currNode==this.NULL");
               return currNode;
           }
           else
           {
               while (currNode.leftChild!=this.NULL)
                   currNode=currNode.leftChild;
           }
           return currNode;
       }

   static class RBNode{

       public RBNode(int key) {
           this.key=key;
       }

        private double key;
        private RBNode parent;
        private RBNode rightChild;
        private RBNode leftChild;
        private String info;
        private String color;

       public RBNode() {

          this.key=-1;
          this.leftChild=null;
          this.rightChild=null;
          this.parent=null;
      }

      public RBNode(int key, String color) {
          this.color=color;
          this.key=key;
          this.leftChild=null;
          this.rightChild=null;
          this.parent=null;

      } 

      public RBNode(int key, String color, RBNode left, RBNode right) {
          this.color=color;
          this.key=key;
          this.leftChild=left;
          this.rightChild=right;

      } 

      public double getKey() {
          return this.key;
      }

      public String getColor() {
          return this.color;
      }  

      public RBNode getParent() {
          return this.parent;
      }     

      public RBNode getLeftChild() {
          return this.leftChild;
      }     

      public RBNode getRightChild() {
          return this.rightChild;
      } 

      public void setColor(String color) {
          this.color=color;
      }  

      public void setKey(double key) {
          this.key=key;
      }  

      public void setParent(RBNode parent) {
          this.parent=parent;
      }     

      public void setLeftChild(RBNode leftChild) {
          this.leftChild=leftChild;
      }     

      public void setRightChild(RBNode rightChild) {
          this.rightChild=rightChild;
      } 


}

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        RBTree t = new RBTree();

        t.insert(14);
        t.insert(11);
        t.insert(7);
        t.insert(8);
        t.delete(11);


    }
```

Comment: please add also the main method you are using to start the whole thing

Comment: if you get a NullPointerException in `w.leftChild.setColor("black")` then it's quite likely that `w` does not have a left child. I suggest running the program in a debugger and figuring out in which cases a node gets constructed without `leftChild` being set.

Comment: @trapo: I added the main method and the deletion method.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: thanks, you are right but I've realised this before. My question is what's is wrong in the algorithm that makes it get to this problem to begin with. The problem is that w has the value off the NULL node (the senital), which by definition has no children.

Comment: and please add all relevant part of your code, so that i can do a test with debugger.

Comment: @trapo: Sorry, now I've added everything relevant.